# 'mat-card-content' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-lazyloading

I  get this error with Angular Universal, lazy loading and share module of material. When I run `npm run dev:ssr` I get this error I think that is combination of lazy loading and Angular Universal.

> 'mat-card-content' is not a known element

```
import { ExceptionModalComponent } from './../../components/exception-

modal/exception-modal.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ExceptionModalRoutingModule } from './exception-modal-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from '../shared/material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExceptionModalComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ExceptionModalRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ExceptionModalModule { }
```

Comment: In your MaterialModule make sure you have the MatCardModule in both the `import` and `export` arrays of the `@NgModule` metadata

Answer (score 1):

You need to add MatCardModule in your ExceptionModalModule.

```
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
```